# Is it possible to write python bindings for swift?

Tags: python, macos, cython

Are there any examples of [python bindings](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) that call code written in swift on MacOS?

I found ways to [call python within swift](https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit), but not the other way around

Specifically, my python application needs to make a call to `DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback()` in apple's Disk Arbitration framework since the `libusb` implementation of registering hotplug callbacks is broken in MacOS. Unfortunately, this framework is only accessible in swift and objective c.

Is there a way to have a python module make calls to swift code?

Comment: Is there any way of calling swift code from C? If so it's probably fairly easy to call it from Python...

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jiaaro/e111f0f64d0cdb8aca38